# Fontspec: bold overrides regular and italic fonts

Tags: fontspec

The bolds are bold, but so is everything else. Italics work, but they are always bold as well. Schola Math works because I have not defined a bold font.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,letterpaper]{book}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage[letterpaper, total={6.5in, 9in}, left=1in, top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=,
  pdfpagelabels=true,
  unicode=true,
  pdfa
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newfontfamily\fonta{texgyreschola-regular.otf}[
  BoldFont = texgyreschola-bold.otf,
  ItalicFont = texgyreschola-italic.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = texgyreschola-bolditalic.otf,
]
\newfontfamily\fontb{texgyreschola-math.otf}[
]
\newfontfamily\fontc{NotoSerifCJK-Medium.ttc}[  % I like the look of Medium, so it is "Upright".
  UprightFeatures = {FontIndex = 0},
  BoldFeatures = {FontIndex = 0},
  BoldFont = NotoSerifCJK-ExtraLight.ttc,  % ExtraLight chosen for "Bold" for contrast.
]

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\fonta  % Set the default font.

\title{{\fontc オペレーシヨん}}
\date{}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\noindent{\bfseries{\huge Table of Contents}\vspace \bigskipamount \par }


%% Schola: Regular -- Incorrect.
\contentsline {part}{Tex Gyre Schola Regular {\fontb ℉}℃\ }{2}{}
%% Schola: Bold -- Good.
\contentsline {part}{\textbf{Tex Gyre Schola Bold {\fontb ℉}℃}\ }{2}{}
%% Schola: Italic -- Incorrect.
\contentsline {part}{\textit{Tex Gyre Schola Italic {\fontb ℉}℃}\ }{2}{}
%% Schola: Bold Italic -- Good.
\contentsline {part}{\textbf{\textit{Tex Gyre Schola Bold Italic {\fontb ℉}℃}}\ }{2}{}
%% Schola Math: Good.
\contentsline {part}{{\fontb Tex Gyre Schola Math {\fontb ℉}℃}\ }{3}{}
%% Noto Serif CJK JP: Regular -- Incorrect.
\contentsline {part}{{\fontc Noto Serif CJK JP Medium {\fontb ℉}℃}\ }{4}{}
%% Noto Serif CJK JP: "Bold" -- Good.
\contentsline {part}{{\fontc \textbf{Noto Serif CJK JP Extra Light {\fontb ℉}℃}}\ }{4}{}
%% Noto Serif CJK JP: Regular -- Incorrect.
\contentsline {part}{{\fontc 本述オペレーシヨン}{\fontb ℉}℃\ }{5}{}
%% Noto Serif CJK JP: "Bold" -- Good.
\contentsline {part}{\textbf{{\fontc 本述オペレーシヨン}{\fontb ℉}℃}\ }{5}{}

\end{document}
```

[image: XeLaTeX Output]

My engine is XeLaTeX.
All fonts should be present.

```
fc-list | grep -i "\(noto serif cjk jp\)\|\(texgyreschola-.*\.otf\)"

/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyreschola-regular.otf: TeX Gyre Schola:style=Regular
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyreschola-bold.otf: TeX Gyre Schola:style=Bold
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyreschola-italic.otf: TeX Gyre Schola:style=Italic
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyreschola-bolditalic.otf: TeX Gyre Schola:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/texgyreschola-math.otf: TeX Gyre Schola Math:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-ExtraLight.ttc: Noto Serif CJK JP,Noto Serif CJK JP ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-Light.ttc: Noto Serif CJK JP,Noto Serif CJK JP Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-Regular.ttc: Noto Serif CJK JP:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-Medium.ttc: Noto Serif CJK JP,Noto Serif CJK JP Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-SemiBold.ttc: Noto Serif CJK JP,Noto Serif CJK JP SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-Bold.ttc: Noto Serif CJK JP:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-Black.ttc: Noto Serif CJK JP,Noto Serif CJK JP Black:style=Black,Regular
```

Comment: You are not setting the default font by calling \fonts once at the begin. Use \setmainfont to declare it.

Comment: also never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xelatex (actually it does nothing where used as fontspec restores the Unicode encoding, but if T1 were selected it would break xetex hyphenation)

Comment: `\contentsline{part}{...}` is defined to use boldface, why are you expecting regular?

Comment: @egreg Yep. Duh. Replacing `part` with `section` fixed the "problem". Thank you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Removed. Hyphenation now works again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fixed. Changed nothing. I suspect it was using Schola by default without me telling it to.